# How to open another screen in JavaFX (not FXML file)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm very new to JavaFX. I want to communication between two window in my program, but I don't know how to do it. For example: after login successfully, another screen will pop up (but I don't want to load the file FXML because I used the loop to generate the toggle buttons in this window instead of dragging-dropping in FXML file). I don't know whether it makes sense or not. If not please forgive me :(

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

Parentroot=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

    primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400,300));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {
@FXML
private TextField usernameField;
@FXML
private TextField passwordField;

@FXML
public void login(){
    if(usernameField.getText().equals("admin") && passwordField.getText().equals("123")){
        successLogin();
    }
}

public void successLogin(){
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("anotherscene.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        stage.show();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

AnotherScene.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class AnotherScene implements Initializable {
    ToggleButton[][] matrix;
    private static final int SIZE = 10;
    private static int length = SIZE;
    private static int width = SIZE;
    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;



@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    Parent root = null;
    try{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("anotherscene.fxml"));
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Seat Number: "));
    borderPane.setLeft(vBox);

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(10);
    borderPane.setCenter(gridPane);

    matrix = new ToggleButton[length][width];


    for(int row = 0; row < length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++){
            matrix[row][col] = new ToggleButton();
            matrix[row][col].setText(row + "" +col);
            matrix[row][col].setPrefWidth(40);
            gridPane.add(matrix[row][col], row, col);

        }
    }

    //      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Hello World");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking two separate questions? On one side how to comunicate between two javafx windows of the same application, and on another side if you should or shouldn't use FXML for all windows? If so are they related in what you are wanting to accomplish?

Comment: I think I mean how can I to communicate the first window (using fxml file) with the second window (using java code). Sorry for the unclear questions

Comment: It's best not to think about it as "communicating between two windows," but simply **communicating between classes**. Whether you use FXML or not, your two windows (Stages) should be represented by at least two classes... just communicate between them as you would any other classes.

Comment: `how can I to communicate the first window (using fxml file) with the second window (using java code)` - the second window is represented by a java class. To communicate with it, as with any java class, use getters, setters, listeners and constructor.

Comment: If this is still interesting, search this forum for DI or “dependency injection”